# Calling SQL server 2008 Stored Procedure from Java

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jakarta-ee

I have created the following stored procedure in SQL server 2008

```
Create PROCEDURE countInfected @infected int out
AS
Select @infected = COUNT(*) from userInfo where userID NOT IN (Select userID from deletedInfo);
```

My java Code is as follow

```
CallableStatement infected = con.prepareCall("exec countInfected()");
infected.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
infected.execute();
    System.out.println("Infected"+ infected.getInt(1));
```

but it generate the following error

> java.lang.NullPointerException at core.dtable.Dbase.stored(Dbase.java:51)

kindly guide me where i am wrong

Comment: Your SP is countNonInfected and you're calling countInfected.

Comment: basically i have both these  procedure, and both have the same code, and both of them are generating the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, i just add a statment to the sql code

```
Create PROCEDURE countInfected @infected int out
AS
Select @infected = COUNT(*) from userInfo where userID NOT IN (Select userID from deletedInfo);
return @infected;
```

and this work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
     try {
        conn     = DBConnection.SQLDB();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false) ;
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        cs = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.xxCount(?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        cs.execute() ;
        System.out.println("INFECTED "+cs.getInt(1));
    }catch (Exception err){
```

Put out parameter in your call to your stored proc.

Comment: thanx for the rply elmer, i dont have any in parameter still i use, dbo.xxCount(?)

Comment: have you tried changing your code from CallableStatement infected = con.prepareCall("exec countInfected()") ; to CallableStatement infected = con.prepareCall("exec countInfected(?)")

Comment: yes i have tried both of them, but still giving problem on cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

Answer (score 0):

As there is not full code posted, I assume `nonInfected.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` is the line 51. What is `nonInfected` , is that required to call the given procedure.

@infected is not used in SQL query, should that not be just out type paramenter instead of in/out.

Try removing `nonInfected.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` completely and run.

Comment: Sorry that is mistyped i will edit it now, the connection above this code is successfully created, other recordset is working but i am having problem with these procedure call. what would you suggest

Comment: Why are you doing `Infected.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` twice.